# localhost not working docker windows 10

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, asp.net-docker-extensions

I am using VS2017 docker support. VS created DockerFile for me and when I build docker-compose file, it creates the container and runs the app on 172.x.x.x IP address. But I want to run my application on localhost.

I did many things but nothing worked. Followed the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application-and-run-examples) as a starter and [building microsoft sample app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/building-sample-app) . The second link is working perfectly but I get HTTP Error 404 when tried the first link approach.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's how *Docker* works. Every container gets its own internal address. If you want to access an interal service using a local port, you expose it with the `-p ` parameter, eg `-p 18000:80` will expose a web app at `127.0.0.1:80`. For specifics, post the parameters you used to create the container

Comment: Downvoters, remember when *you* tried to create your first web site running on that new thing called `Docker`? How long did you spend trying to find out how to talk to it?

Comment: Please specify the Windows and Docker versions you are running, as well as the command-line parameters you used. Not `Windows 10` but eg `10.0.16299.15`. You can get this by typing `ver` at a command line. For  docker: `docker version`. Do you already run something at port 80? Perhaps IIS with a default site? Have you tried *changing* the forwarded port, eg to `18000` with `-p 18000:80` and connect to `localhost:18000` ?

Comment: Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4 and Windows 10 pro Version 10.0.15063 .... I used to speify port 5000:80 but nothing works... So I reset the docker to default and now its working on linux container, earlier I was working on windows container as guided by microsoft site

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *Windows* containers. Linux containers are for *Linux* apps. What exactly is that `nothing works` that you tried? As for the tutorial, you don't need these steps anymore, VS templates already provide Docker support. You can just create a new web app from the template and run it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to access the example posted on Docker Docs, that you pointed out as not working, follow the below steps,

1 - List all the running docker containers

```
docker ps -a
```

After you run this command you should be able to view all your docker containers that are currently running and you should see a container with the name `webserver` listed there, if you have followed the docker docs example correctly.

2 - Get the IP address where your `webserver` container is running. To do that run the following command.

```
 docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" webserver
```

You should now get the IP address which the `webserver` container is running, hope you are familiar with this step as it was even available within the building Microsoft sample app example that you attached with the question.

Access the IP address you get once running the above command and you should see the desired output.

Answering to your first question (accessing docker container with localhost in docker for windows), in Windows host you cannot access the container with localhost due to a limitation in the default NAT network stack. A more detailed explanation for this issue can be obtained  by visiting this [**link**](https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/). Seems like the docker documentation is not yet updated but this issue only exists in Windows hosts.

There is an issue reported for this as well - Follow this **[link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/458)** to see that.

Hope this helps you out.

**EDIT**

The solution for this issue seems to be coming in a future Windows release. Yet that release comes out this limitation is available in Windows host. Follow this link -> https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/181

Comment: That's an old issue. I'm using SQL Server inside a container with port forwarding  and connect through `localhost` just fine

Comment: Maybe its because of an old version. The docker docs example which was referred in the question has all the steps pointed out clearly and failing that example to access via localhost would only happen due to the above issue.

Comment: It would also happen if something else run on port 80, like the default web site of IIS, or any other deployed web project. Docker won't complain if the port is already taken

Comment: Yes agree with that

Comment: thanks for the answer... I searched deeply and got the answer. I switched to windows container as I was following microsoft tutorial so it mapped onto 172.x.x.x , now I switched back to linux container and everything is running fine.

Comment: @UsamaSaleem that is *not* a solution. There's nothing wrong with *Windows* containers. If you needed a *Linux* container for your application, it means that you were building a Llinux app.

Comment: @UsamaSaleem can you please specify the Windows and Docker versions you are running, as well as the command-line parameters you used as Panagiotis earlier mentioned. So we can find the real issue behind your problem.

Comment: Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4 and Windows 10 pro Version 10.0.15063 .... and command line parameters -d -p --name etc from the tutorial

Comment: @UsamaSaleem is ther any other application running on port 80 in your Windows host? Whats the port that IIS server runs on?

Comment: @RavinduFernando unable to find

Comment: @UsamaSaleem try this and tell! https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/vault-products/troubleshooting/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Vault-Install/files/GUID-16485246-1889-405F-9A23-E25349092699-htm.html

Comment: By default its running on port 80. So doing a port forwarding is the best way.  Try docker run -d -p 5000:80 --name webserver nginx insted of docker run command provided in the docker docs and access it via http://localhost:5000

Comment: @UsamaSaleem Refer the answer given by Panagiotis to this question to understand what is really happening if you are still unclear.

Comment: @UsamaSaleem I updated the answer with the issue link you have provided

Answer (score 9):

Most likely a different application already runs at port 80. You'll have to forward your web site to a *different* port, eg:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:80 --name myapp myasp
```

And point your browser to `http://localhost:5000`.

When you start a container you specify which inner ports will be exposed as ports on the host through the `-p` option. `-p 80:80` exposes the *inner* port `80` used by web sites to the host's port 80.

Docker won't complain though if *another* application already listens at port 80, like IIS, another web application or any *tool* with a web interface that runs on 80 by default.

The solution is to:

1. Make sure nothing else runs on port 80 or
2. Forward to a different port.

Forwarding to a different port is a lot easier.

To ensure that you *can* connect to a port, use the telnet command, eg :

```
telnet localhost 5000
```

If you get a blank window immediatelly, it means a server is up and running on this port. If you get a message and timeout after a while, it means nobody is running. You anc use this both to check for free ports *and* ensure you can connect to your container web app.

*PS* I run into this just a week ago, as I was trying to set up a SQL Server container for tests. I run 1 default and 2 named instances already, and `docker` didn't complain at all when I tried to create the container. Took me a while to realize what was wrong.

Comment: I followed your commands but I got this when connecting to localhost -> "This site can’t be reached", besides I ran telnet command on 80 and I got a blank window(server is up), then I ran on 5000 and I got "Could not open connection to the host, on port 5000"

Comment: @RavinduFernando I can't, that's what I was trying to fix.I am only able to access it through NATed IP... I found this reply related to my problem..
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/181
read the last comment

Comment: @UsamaSaleem so that means the answer I added is still valid ryt?

Comment: according to my research, Yes. but if someone have other ideas or opinions, I am here and happy to apply.

Answer (score 6):

For those who encountering this issue in 2022, changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` solved an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to move the `-p` argument to the front, after the `run`. The order of arguments makes a difference..

So this will **not** work:

```
docker run --rm example/app -p 5000:80
```

And this will work:

```
docker run -p 5000:80 --rm example/app
```

Comment: This solved the issue I was having.  Was running container from CLI and had the -p statements AFTER the image name, and the ports would not appear in netstat.  Running from Docker Desktop, the ports would appear in netstat.  Wish I would have found this answer 4 hours ago.  Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score -2):

There is other problem too
You must have correct order with parameters

This is WRONG

```
docker run container:latest -p 5001:80
```

This sequence start container but parameter -p is ignore, therefore container have no ports mapping

This is good

```
docker run -p 5001:80 container:latest
```

Comment: the ordering of program arguments not be mandatory for passing the arguments