# Can't access to localhost:8080 with docker on windows 10

Tags: node.js, docker, localhost, windows-10

When running my `docker-compose-development.yaml` on my computer, I can't connect to `http://localhost:8080`.

Also, I can run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yaml exec web curl http://localhost:8080` and I got a result. So it seems to not be a code problem.

What I've already done:

- Connect directly on container IP with `$ docker inspect ...`
- Try on another Windows 10 laptop (**it works**)
- Change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`
- Try another port than `8080`

This is my `$ docker version` :

```
Client:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce
 API version:  1.34
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   1caf76c
 Built:        Mon Nov 20 18:30:11 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce
 API version:  1.34 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.5
 Git commit:   1caf76c
 Built:        Mon Nov 20 18:39:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:9.1-alpine

RUN npm install -g nodemon


WORKDIR /opt/webserver/
COPY . /opt/webserver
RUN npm install

CMD  ["npm","run","start"]
EXPOSE 8080

RUN rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

This is my `docker-compose-development.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/soundtrack/webapp
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ".:/opt/webserver:rw"
  database:
    image: mongo:3.4.10
```

`ps` command from `docker-compose`:

```
$ docker-compose -f .\docker-compose-development.yaml ps
      Name                    Command             State           Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
webapp_database_1   docker-entrypoint.sh mongod   Up      27017/tcp
webapp_web_1        npm run start                 Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

Answer (score 8):

I ran my container:

```
docker run -d -it -p 10080:80 --name=container-cool-name <container-id>
```

And I could see my running app with curl (inside the container)

```
docker exec -ti container-cool-name bash
#curl localhost:80
```

[Here](https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-connect-to-container-on-localhost-with-port-mapping/52716/7?u=manatico) I read:

> If you’re using Docker Toolbox

"`docker-machine ip` will tell you"

My app was correctly displaying at `192.168.99.100:10080`

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps,

1 - List all the running docker containers

```
docker ps -a
```

After you run this command you should be able to view all your docker containers that are currently running and you should see a container with the name webapp_web_1 listed there.

2 - Get the IP address where your webserver container is running. To do that run the following command.

```
 docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" webapp_web_1
```

Try accessing the IP which is shown after running above command and access your running container with that IP instead of localhost.

I have answered to a simillar question related to this exact problem on Windows. Please refer it via this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47011886/4334340) to get a detailed idea on why this issue prevails.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Alternatively, `docker-machine ip default` gave me the IP address.

Comment: All I get back is `<no value>`