# Unable to run Flask App using Docker in Windows-10

Tags: python, windows, docker, flask

I've installed and configured docker (as per documentation) and I am trying to build a flask application using `tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8`. I've built a hello-world application, and have tested it locally by running `python manage.py` and the application runs successfully. [Link to full Code-File](https://github.com/ZenithClown/flask-docker-template).

My docker version and installation is as below:

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8

ENV INSTALL_PATH /usr/src/helloworld
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

# install net-tools
RUN apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    net-tools \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set working directory
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

# setup flask environment
# install all requirements
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy all files and folder to docker
COPY . .

# run the application in docker environment
CMD [ "python", "./manage.py" ]
```

I built the application with `docker build --tag hello-world:test .` and running the application as: `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 hello-world:test` successfully.

[image]

However, I'm unable to open the application in `localhost:5000` or `0.0.0.0:5000` or any other port. The application is running, as I can see it from the CLI:

[image]

But, from browser the page is not reachable:

[image]

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010047/localhost-not-working-docker-windows-10) mentions to check the IP address:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" hungry_engelbart
>> <no value>
```

Found another solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498101/cant-access-to-localhost8080-with-docker-on-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1), but `docker-machine` is currently deprecated.

I'm new to docker, but I have tried to run the same thing following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-flask-application-using-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04), but faced similar issues.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the address to `0.0.0.0` like what worked in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66381355/4676641)? You'd make this change [here](https://github.com/ZenithClown/flask-docker-template/blob/master/manage.py#L31) and replace `localhost` with `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Yes, tried both `localhost:5000` and `0.0.0.0:5000` got same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am able to solve this. I had to configure a new `inbound rules` under Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules > New Inbound Rules. Create a new rule that will allow a range of local IP addresses, which in my case was `198.168.0.1:198.168.0.100`. Finally, you need to run the application at `0.0.0.0` as pointed by @tentative in the comments. :)