# Dockerized apache server not exposing port 80

Tags: apache, reactjs, docker, apache2

I am trying to run a React application inside a docker container. My application image was built with the following Dockerfile:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
LABEL autor="Ed de Almeida"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN mkdir /tmp/myapp
COPY . /tmp/myapp
RUN cd /tmp/myapp && npm install
RUN cd /tmp/myapp && npm run build
RUN cd /tmp/myapp/build && cp -Rvf * /var/www/html
RUN cd /var/www && chown -Rvf www-data:www-data html/
EXPOSE 80

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

As you may see, I create a production build, copy it to the standard directory of the Apache server and then run the Apache server. I even exposed port 80, the Apache default port.

I am creating the image with

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

and running the container with

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name myapp myimage
```

I am probably missing something, because I am new to Docker, because the container is there, up and running, but when I point my browser to http://localhost I got nothing.

I entered the container with

```
docker exec -it myapp bash
```

and the application is running fine inside it.

Any hints?

Comment: When you go inside the container, try curling the specified endpoint, to make sure that the issue is with exposing ports. Also, there  is a difference between a connection refused error or other errors in the browser.

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1` runs fine inside the container and returns the expected.

Comment: Are you running on windows or mac?

Comment: My host is Windows. Docker image for node is built over Debian Jessie.

Comment: I have given a detailed answer for similar kind of issue when running Docker in Windows. Refer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47011886/4334340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running on windows, Docker will be running on a virtual machine that is running in the backgound. Thus you need to connect to this virtual machine and not to localhost.

You can get the machine ip by running:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

This will give you the IP address of the machine, which you can use to connect from the browser.